# Bizarre program behavior about 'char'

Tags: c++, string, if-statement, char

I'm writing this code just for fun while learning the if-else statements. There is a weird behavior when I digit 10e, the program returns the error, but I can't understand why! I mean with the other unit such as 'd' or 'y' it works perfectly, but when I digit 'e' it goes nut!

Basically, the program converts the number the user input, in the unit that follows that number. Example, if you digit 10**d** it will return how much is 10£ in Japanese Yen.

Have a look:

```
// money_exchange.cpp : A money exchange simulator that converts any rate to pound.
// The standard rates can be updated daily.


#include "stdafx.h"
#include "../../Library/std_lib_facilities.h"

// 19/03/18 - Exchange Rates
const double euro = 1.13706;
const double dollar = 1.40369;
const double krone = 1.83428;
const double yen = 148.816;

double user_pocket = 0.0;
double user_account = 100.0;
string user_name = "ernest";
string user_pass = "pass";

int main()
{
    cout << "Good Morning. Exchange rates loading...\n";
    cout << "Please login into your account by writing username and password separated by a whitspace: ";
    string login_name = " ";
    string login_pass = " ";

    cin >> login_name >> login_pass;

    if (login_name == user_name && login_pass == user_pass) {
        // User information resume:
        cout << "\nWelcome " << user_name << ". I'm loading your information...\n";
        cout << "Name: " << user_name << "\nPocket: " << user_pocket << " GBP" << "\nAccount: " << user_account << " GBP\n";

        // Options available
        cout << "\nI'm sorry but the only options available is: Exchange Rates\n";
        cout << "Please digit the amount of money you would like to convert followed by a unit ( E,D,Y,K ): ";
        double money = 0.0;
        char unit = ' ';
        cin >> money >> unit;

        // Convertion selection
        if (unit == 'e') {
            cout << "\nResult: " << money << "GBP = " << euro * money << "EUR\n";
            cout << "At the moment I can execute just one computation at time, please restart the application.\n";
            cout << "Thank you " << user_name << '\n';
        }
        else if (unit == 'd')
        {
            cout << "\nResult: " << money << "GBP = " << dollar * money << "USD\n";
            cout << "At the moment I can execute just one computation at time, please restart the application.\n";
            cout << "Thank you " << user_name << '\n';
        }
        else if (unit == 'k')
        {
            cout << "\nResult: " << money << "GBP = " << krone * money << "NOK\n";
            cout << "At the moment I can execute just one computation at time, please restart the application.\n";
            cout << "Thank you " << user_name << '\n';
        }
        else if (unit == 'y')
        {
            cout << "\nResult: " << money << "GBP = " << yen * money << "JPY\n";
            cout << "At the moment I can execute just one computation at time, please restart the application.\n";
            cout << "Thank you " << user_name << '\n';
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "\nSomething went wrong! Make sure to follow the instruction ( 10y will produce 10 pound in Yen )";
            cout << "\nAt the moment I can execute just one computation at time, please restart the application.\n";
            cout << "Thank you " << user_name << '\n';
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // Login failed
        cout << "\nUsername or Password not in the database, please try again!";
    }

    keep_window_open();

    return 0;
}
```

When you start the program, try to digit 10e and you can see the program returning the error. If you write 10 (space) e it works. But with the other units you don't need the space between the digit and the unit, it'll work anyway. I'm new to programming, so it is probably a stupid error.

Comment: The `e` is a normal part of floating point values. Like `10e2` for the value `100`.

Comment: So basically, because of that, you can't use 10e in c++? How could I fix this? If for instance, I must use 10e.

Comment: Use another way of reading and parsing the input.

Comment: In general, avoid using `cin >>` on numeric variables.  Instead, read a string, validate it, and parse it.

Comment: So how should I read the user input ( money ) in this case? Can you give me a small example? Oh and hey, thanks for the help guys! =)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is happening because your `money` variable is a double. In C++, doubles can be referenced using scientific notation (e), so your `cin` statement is reading `10e` as 10*10^(?). It's not reading any exponent and also not reading anything into unit.

Comment: Oh got it! But I need that variable as a double, in this way my user can type also double format. Like 10.5 dollars...

Comment: use 'u' for euro instead of 'e'

Comment: Yeah, i thought as well of changing that, but I want to find a way to use 'e', it will be good as exercise! Shall I ready the value of unit in a different way? Converting it? I don't know. Mh.

Comment: I didn't reach yet the chapter about parse statement, probably I should stop for now this code and edit it once I learned the parse method!

Comment: You will want to read the input as a string and then use a `for` loop to read the string until you find one of the characters you're using to notate currency, or a space character. Then you can convert the number part to a float using the `atof` function.

Comment: Though, if you ever have to deal with a hyperinflated currency (e.g., Zimbabwean dollar), you might *want* to support scientific notation ;-)